# What do flag reviewers see?

Tags: discussion

I recently came upon [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29306761/1050672). The original version of the answer was simply a comment to the question. I flagged it as "Not an Answer". Since then, it has been edited to so that the flag doesn't really apply anymore.

So, when the reviewers see this, do they see the original edit of the answer I flagged, or do they see the revised?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

They see this (https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/7494103);

> [image]

In other words, they see the post *as it is at the time they carry out the review*, not as it was at the time you flagged the post. This applies for all flags (posts, comments) of all varieties.

Comment: They should change this. I hate seeing 'rejected' in my profile.

Comment: Yeah, questions that have been changed to follow the site rules should be deleted because *muh profile beauty*

Comment: @Chipperyman Or the flag should just be removed. Or maybe approved flags should still count if the post was edited (just in case someone decides to edit their answer repeatedly to avoid flags), but rejected flags should be removed.

Comment: Who cares, it's just a number on an internet page.

Comment: I feel like that's a lot of work for a next-to-useless feature.

Comment: Or at least a notification to the reviewer that the post has been edited since the flag went up.

Comment: @Nit To be fair, it's a bit more than "just" a number: [*"You are awarded additional bonus flags when you flag correctly - one bonus flag for every ten net helpful flags (helpful flags **minus declined flags**)"*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts).

Comment: I got my job due to my StackOverflow profile being of good standing. (Not really, but you get my point).

Comment: @Qix If a couple of flags this or that away on Stack Overflow is all that decided whether you got a job or not...

Comment: @MyCodeSucks Suppose you are a reviewer and you see a notification that the post has been edited since the flag was posted. Is that going to change how you handle the post? *No, because your review actions should be based on the content and quality of the post, NOT on the fact that a flag exists.*