# Better review handling of posts that have been edited since flagging

Tags: feature-request, flags, declined-flags, disputed-flags

I recently asked [What do flag reviewers see?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288843/what-do-flag-reviewers-see) here on Meta. Based upon the few comments that the answer got, and reading up on [flagging privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts), I'd like to make a request that if a question/answer is edited after the flag was thrown, then review of the flag could have another option to "Disregard flag". That way, this doesn't count toward declined flag status. And it lets the reviewer know that the post was changed **after** the flag.

Alternatively, send the flagger a notification that the content has been changed, and allow them to revoke their flag, or keep it in place. This latter option could also keep many items from reaching the Review queue that don't need to be there.

I understand the review is for the content at the time of the review, but some consideration should be taken toward the flagger if the original post is edited. If a person is flagging items appropriately, but they all get edited and the flags get declined, then that person is less likely to continue to partake in the flagging process.

I see this as less about a number on the Internet, and more about getting people who want to have quality questions/answers on the site.

Answer (score 27):

I flag with reckless abandon† and also comment freely whenever I think a flagged post can be improved, often for simple things like "include code or an exception message"; a few times, I've gone back and found a flag declined because my comment was followed up on or the post otherwise fixed up. So I certainly sympathize, and have even at times thought similarly myself. But I have over 1400 helpful flags and exactly 10 declined, of which fewer than half were declined because the post changed under me; even the 23 more disputed flags only add another half-dozen or so such posts. So I'm not sure this is enough of a problem to really worry about, and most of the solutions seem unnecessary.

However, I would certainly support flag retraction abilities in order to reduce review load, *especially* if the same mechanism could be used to notify us of downvoted posts that have since changed.

<sub>†*Well, whenever I see a post that needs it.*</sub>

Comment: worth noting that [since recently](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251876/165773), comments seem to be triggering saving of a current revision, so that whoever reviews a flag submitted _after comment_, has a better chance to see what it was when flagged, without that [meta-tag:grace-period] fluff

Comment: @gnat That's true, but I'm not convinced that it changes much about what happens with the flags. If the flag is disputed/declined based on review queue votes (typically LQ queue), the edit history won't make a difference at all. And if a moderator handles the flag (which is much rarer), I don't believe they typically look at the history either. If the flag is not justified based on the current version of the post, it gets declined.

Comment: @RetoKoradi well for VLQ flags, it changes much indeed. Edits that become explicit instead of being buried in grace period, automatically validate such flags as helpful. As for NAA, it's not as clear cut, but at least moderator now _can_ see that post has improved after flag and proceed accordingly (dismiss flag as helpful without actioning post). Granted, this won't save NAA flags on edited posts from being rejected by regular reviewers in LQ queue but this doesn't look much of an issue since this resolves flag into painless [disputed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/95277/165773)

Comment: @gnat: It looks to me as though disputation only happens if Edit is chosen *in the queue*, by a reviewer. I would be happy to be wrong on this, though.

Comment: well in my experience (~250 declined and ~180 disputed flags at 4 sites), _any_ edit resolved VLQ to helpful. And I had NAA/VLQ declines _only_ from moderators (easy to recognize by decline message)

Comment: @NathanTuggy ...[this recent post at MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/252854/165773) suggests that currently edits automatically dismiss NAA flags as helpful: [moderator view screen shot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/nneDw.png)

Answer (score -8):

I dislike voting to close brand new questions as too vague. If I encounter a question in the review queue that's less than an hour old, and it's too vague, then I'll usually comment on the post and then skip it.

Comment: see [Vote to close unclear questions immediately after commenting?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256331/839601) "Vote to close right away.

In the aggregate, this benefits those who ask questions..."

Comment: I've seen that post. I just prefer to spend my limited close votes on questions where the OP has had some warning. We all know how big the close vote queue is. If the OP can be nudged to improve his votes without expending close/reopen votes on it, those are reviewer resources that can be spent elsewhere.

Comment: your reasoning makes certain sense (I also sometimes have to skip "less close-worthy" questions when I'm short on votes). You might be getting downvotes because answer doesn't make that clear for readers (many ignore comments), so that it looks like you suggest to just indiscriminately skip commented questions, even when someone isn't really interested in "saving" close votes for even-worse cases