# Should edits really make flags obsolete

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flags, disputed-flags

First off, just to make sure I'm not making a big fuss about nothing: I understand that when a flag is marked as disputed, it won't be shown to a moderator because the issue is considered to be resolved, right?

Now for the problem:
Today I flagged several questions that were edited shortly afterwards. All edits were minor edits and did not resolve the reason why I flagged the question. But because of the edit my flags were marked disputed and won't be shown to a moderator (if I understand correctly how disputed flags work).

On top of that, I can't raise those flags again, because I already did flag those questions.

Here are the questions so you can take a look for yourself:

- [Migration from InnoDB to Deep Engine for MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29514086/migration-from-innodb-to-deep-engine-for-mysql) (too broad)
- [Implementing head up display in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29514844/implementing-head-up-display-in-android) (too broad)
- [How to let overflow-x visible and hide overflow-y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29515717/how-to-let-overflow-x-visible-and-hide-overflow-y) (duplicate of [CSS overflow-x: visible; and overflow-y: hidden; causing scrollbar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421966/css-overflow-x-visible-and-overflow-y-hidden-causing-scrollbar-issue))

This is neither about my ego nor about my flag stats (like [this similar question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289006/better-review-handling-of-posts-that-have-been-edited-since-flagging)), this is about stuff that needs moderator attention and doesn't get it because of a technicality.

On the other hand I see the need to keep the workload for moderators as low as possible, so I understand why an edit would mark a flag as disputed if an edit improved the quality of a question/answer.

So, would it be possible to

- either alert someone that a post was flagged if they edit it and ask them if the flag should remain after their edit (which would be a bad solution if the OP was the one editing)
- or alert the person who raised the flag after the post was edited and ask them for confirmation or retraction of their flag (basically introducing a new status for flags like "needs confirmation" or "on hold")

Comment: _"alert someone that a post was flagged if they edit it and ask them if the flag should remain after their edit"_ That would likely _never_ happen. OPs of questions being flagged for closure could just add a space or something else trivial to their post and be able to invalidate any flags on their question that editing would have cleared. Granted, this wouldn't work for close votes, but if the flag is what would have gotten the post the attention needed to get the close votes...

Comment: I know, I thought about that too, but forgot to mention it. Thanks for pointing it out, I included that concern in my post.

Comment: related: [Edits shouldn't dismiss “not an answer” flags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/252854/165773) (at MSE)